# Facebook Graph Query with PHP

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

So I am trying to fetch images posted with a certain hashtag in facebook. I am using the facebook php api. This is my code:

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('my-api-key', 'secret');

$session=FacebookSession::newAppSession();


try {
  $session->validate();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  var_dump($ex);
  echo $ex->getMessage();
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
  // Graph API returned info, but it may mismatch the current app or have expired.
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}

$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/gatos'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
var_dump($graphObject);
```

I know that the request I am executing is not for pulling hashtags, but anyways, I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message 'Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api' in /var/www/experiments/gatopull/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php:104 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/experiments/gatopull/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php(280): Facebook\FacebookRequestException::create('{"error":{"mess...', Object(stdClass), 400) #1 /var/www/experiments/gatopull/config/facebook_api.php(36): Facebook\FacebookRequest->execute() #2 /var/www/experiments/gatopull/config/apicontroller.php(2): require_once('/var/www/experi...') #3 /var/www/experiments/gatopull/index.php(3): require_once('/var/www/experi...') #4 {main} thrown in /var/www/experiments/gatopull/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php on line 104
```

My questions are:

1. Do I need a user access-token to search hashtags, or is it
   sufficient with the client token?
2. I know the request I need to do with curl or by url, but how do I make this request with the fb api? Here is the url request:
   https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=hashtag&type=post&limit=999&access_token=myaccesstoken
3. Is there any php library to do this with more social networks?

thanks!

Comment: You can not search for hashtags, because you can not search posts any more – that search functionality has been removed with API v2.

Comment: And `gatos` seem to be a username – you can not query information about users any more via that either, the `username` field has also been removed in v2.